# Upload Dataset failed with CartoDB in Ubuntu 12.04 VM

Tags: carto, ubuntu

I have tried installing CartoDB in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS first on which I could not import datasets. I have raised the question on this viz., [Import Files failed with cartoDB installed in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268891/import-files-failed-with-cartodb-installed-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts). But could not find a solution.

As an alternative, I have tried installing the CartoDB following the instructions from the manual "http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html" in Ubuntu 12.04 VM. But again when I try to import any file (CSV or shapefile in zip format), I am getting same import error which is decribed as follows.

**Error Code :** 2001

**Error Description :** Unable to load data

**Imports Log:**

```
{"user":"development","state":"pending","tables":0,"imported_tables":0,"failed_tables":0,"error_code":null,"import_timestamp":"2018-01-30T21:13:16-08:00","queue_server":"ubuntu","database_host":"localhost","service_name":"public_url","data_type":"file","is_sync_import":false,"import_time":0.001509,"file_stats":{},"resque_ppid":null,"user_timeout":13981,"error_source":null,"id":"0a0952bb-b387-48f5-8fbb-e7b5c5be04c5","total_size":0,"cartodbfy_time":0.0,"import_throughput":0.0,"cartodbfy_throughtput":null,"cartodbfy_import_ratio":0.0,"extra_options":{},"retrieved_items":0}
{"user":"development","state":"failure","tables":1,"imported_tables":0,"failed_tables":1,"error_code":2001,"import_timestamp":"2018-01-30T21:13:18-08:00","queue_server":"ubuntu","database_host":"localhost","service_name":"public_url","data_type":"file","is_sync_import":false,"import_time":2.67401697,"file_stats":[{"filename":"sample_csv.csv","type":".csv","size":201,"file_rows":null,"imported_rows":null,"error_percent":null,"fallback_executed":null}],"resque_ppid":9926,"user_timeout":13981,"error_source":"user","id":"0a0952bb-b387-48f5-8fbb-e7b5c5be04c5","total_size":201,"cartodbfy_time":0.0,"import_throughput":75.16781017287262,"cartodbfy_throughtput":null,"cartodbfy_import_ratio":0.0,"extra_options":{},"retrieved_items":0}
```

**CSV File to Import:**

```
lon,lat
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
-50.09765625,38.95940879245421
```

Also, I am getting a warning like:

> "ignoring statsd, because there were a error loading the config"

while starting the server. Do we need to perform any additional configuration for "app_config.yml" or "database.yml" in cartodb?

Comment: Can you take a look into the logs and share any errors you see there?

Comment: Updated the question @JorgeSanz

Comment: Could you share the `ogr2ogr` configuration in your `app_config.yml`? It should point to a valid `ogr2ogr` installation in your machine (i.e. executing the `which` statement in your machine must point to a valid path). Also, althought not related to the problem, take into account that all the points that you are trying to import have the same coordinates

Comment: the app_config.yml configuration for ogr2ogr is available at https://pastebin.com/R0yhERJa.

 Also, I have installed ogr2ogr2 as suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/xI15ygEy4Fo

Comment: I could not even see the rails error. I am following the instruction from this document https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cartodb/latest/cartodb.pdf which found to be released on 31 Jan 2018

Comment: Could you post the result of executing `ogr2ogr --version` in a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I could successfully import data (CSV and GeoJSON) in cartoDB now. The problem was I had GDAL 1.10 previously installed and now being upgraded to GDAL 2.1.3 which resolved the issue. Moreover the cartoDB is working fine for import dataset in Ubuntu 14.04 also.

Comment: But now I got another issue in uploading shapefiles that gives me "SHP Normalization error"(3009). Actually, I am exporting the data from cartodb to SHP files and uploading it again which also gives same error. Need to find out on this issue again.

Comment: Could you open another question with this new problem? This would improve the discoverability of the question for others with the same problem

Comment: Okay Sure.. Done at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270094/shape-normalization-error-while-importing-shapefiles-in-cartodb