# Shape Normalization Error while importing shapefiles in cartoDB

Tags: shapefile, carto, import

I had succesfully installed CartoDB in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM and could import CSV and GeoJSON without any error. When I try to load shapefiles, the following error pops out.

**Error Code :** 3009

**Error :** SHP Normalization Error

My environment for python is Version 2.7.6 and I have latest GDAL installed which is of version 2.1.3.

I have tried to export the uploaded GeoJSON file and then try to import in CartoDB to prevent any encoding/projection issue but still no success.

Comment: Can you share the dataset?

Comment: The uploaded dataset is available in the following link...https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-DjZEYYtUyn6eCaVmTc56RiXQHNVM5q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to import the dataset to my www.carto.com so it looks like it is something related to your local installation. Sorry, but I cannot help you more.